# samtools and trinity causing inconsistencies in conda env

Tags: python, linux, command-line, conda

I'm trying to install busco, detonate, and transrate in conda but I keep getting this error:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - bioconda/linux-64::samtools==1.11=h6270b1f_0
  - bioconda/linux-64::trinity==2.9.1=h8b12597_0
```

This is the command I enter

```
conda install -c bioconda busco -y
```

So far, I've tried adding conda-forge and bioconda to my channels, and then I've tried updating samtools and trinity, and conda install anaconda. Attempting any of these things just brings the same error as above.

Any ideas on other things I should try?

Thanks!

Comment: Try installing everything into a fresh conda environment. It looks like something, possibly something unrelated, is pinning things in your environment. If you can't install a package in a fresh environment, report it to the recipe maintainers.

Comment: @MattThompson Creating a fresh env should work, just tested it. You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try installing everything into a fresh conda environment. It looks like something, possibly something unrelated, is pinning things in your environment. If you can't install a package in a fresh environment, report it to the recipe maintainers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately. I think it may be an issue with the remote computer I'm trying to run these things on then

Comment: Okay, issue fixed (kinda)! I created a new environment with Python 3.9, and Detonate and Transrate were able to install. Oddly, these packages are run in 3.6, so I'm not sure why a fresh environment running 3.7 was unable to install them. Busco has been stuck on 'solving environment' for over 24 hours now, so I'm not sure why that is, but I'm glad the other packages were able to install.

Comment: `conda`'s solver (currently) is not very good, recommend `mamba` as a drop-in replacement. Also recommend avoiding anything Python 3.6 as it's EOL

Comment: Amazing, installing with mamba had everything ready in less than a minute. Thank you so much!